# Is CallKit available on iPad?

Tags: ios, callkit

I just wonder if I can use [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) APIs on iPad.

My voice call app worked great on iPhone with CallKit but on iPad, the incoming call screen is not displayed.

I used CallKit to display the incoming call, should I use a different approach on iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, CallKit works universally on iPhones and iPads as well.

Here is how the incoming call notifier screen looks ([using the Ray Wenderlich "Hotline" test app as an example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/150015/callkit-tutorial-ios)):

[image: The incoming call notifier screen of CallKit on an iPad]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CallKit should work the same on iPad as it does on iPhone including showing the native incoming call UI when your app reports a new incoming call.

If you are seeing issues I suggest filing a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple and attaching the necessary diagnostic logs, using instructions at

> https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/iOS_Logs/sysdiagnose_Logging_Instructions.pdf